# How to add a fallback font for a non supported character in font-face?

Tags: html, css, utf-8, font-face, hebrew

I am using a custom font face for the Hebrew language on a site and I am missing the whole set of English characters a-b, A-Z.

Right now I use the font (reformaregular) on the `body` tag:

```
body { font-family: 'reformaregular', Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif; }
```

English characters come up in the system default of a serif font Times New Roman on windows:

[image]

Notice the English serif at the bottom and custom hebrew font at the top.

Aside from tagging everything with a custom `.en` class;

My question is **how do I add a fallback for the English font?**

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a way to check if a character is supported by the font, if not to fall back to another font ? You can't do that (or I at least never heard of a way to achive this)

Comment: @drip I don't really need to check anything, just make sure the browser falls back to using `Arial` or some other `sans-serif` font instead of the default `serif`.

Comment: Ok. And you are 100% sure that there is no css overwriting the font for the email addrress ? Since there is no logic for a text to fallback to serif, when there are default fonts there. And are you 100% sure that all the fonts are converted properly (for characters and numbers) ?

Comment: Hey, so I tried out a demo with one of googles early access fonts and it seems that it might be the font itself that is not setup correctly.  This is [the bin](http://jsbin.com/yecin/1). i.e. I have to ask the font vendor if the fonts are setup correclty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually if I understand your question right you can by using css `unicode-range`

see @font-face/unicode-range at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

and a quick example:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Almoni;
    src: url(Almoni.ttf);
    unicode-range: U+0590-05FF;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: CoolOtherLanguageFont;
    src: url(CoolOtherLanguageFont.ttf);
    unicode-range: U+0370-03FF, U+1F00-1FFF;
}
body {
    font-family: Almoni, CoolOtherLanguageFont, Helvetica;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have different font for different languages. If your Hebrew font does not have English character set (or digits for example) than you are out of luck. The only way we found was to run a javascript that detects non-Hebrew charset and adds an `.english` or [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang) to the text with the correct English font.

Comment: can you post the script?

Comment: I don't have something that I can share, but you can use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226456/detecting-hebrew-words-in-document-via-javascript to detect Hebrew chars, or do the opposite and use [A-Za-z0-9 _@.-] to detect text nodes that are only English. It's complicated, slow and I would not recommend it. Better to use a different font that have both Hebrew and English chars.

Comment: Great, I won't be using it but it's good to know. Thanks for the refrence

Comment: @hitautodestruct it is customary to upvote an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Actually it was your comment that was helpful. Why don't you add it to your answer..

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find out why my 'fallback' wasn't working but this explains it.